# setInterval works just one time, then stops

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create a countdown function but it works just at the begining and then stops.

```
var rek_inter = setInterval(cnt(s_, d), 1000);    

function cnt(deg, deg2) {
    deg--;
    while (deg < 0) {
        deg = 59;
        deg2--;
    }
    if (deg2 < 0) {
        $('#s_').html("ok");
    } else if (deg2 >= 0) {
        var d_sn = fixd(deg2);
        var s_sn = fixd(deg);
        $('#s_').html(d_sn + ":" + s_sn);
    }
}

function fixd(g) {
    if (g < 10) {
        return '0' + g;
    }
    return g;
}
```

I tried that, too;

```
var rek_inter = setInterval(function() {cnt(s_, d);}, 1000);
```

But result was same.

If I put the function into the interval function like that:

```
    var rek_inter = setInterval(function () {

        s_--;
        while (s_ < 0) {
            s_ = 59;
            d--;
        }
        if (d < 0) {
            $('#s_').html("ok");
        } else if (d >= 0) {
            var d_sn = fixd(d);
            var s_sn = fixd(s_);
            $('#s_').html(d_sn + ":" + s_sn);
        }
    }, 1000);

    function fixd(g) {
        if (g < 10) {
            return '0' + g;
        }
        return g;
    }
```

It works. But I need that as I wrote first at the top. What could be the problem and solution here?

Comment: http://jsbeautifier.org

Comment: can you share your html? or put this in a fiddle?

Comment: Your second attempt (where you wrap the call to "cnt" in a function) would work. I suggest you re-try that.

Comment: @Pointy I tried over and over again, but not working :/

Comment: for the record, using a while loop as an if is quite surprising :-)

Comment: @GameAlchemist I really don't know why or how I decided to use "while", I just wrote that for no reason :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I have lot of s_, s_2, s_3.... and d, d1, d2... values and I want to use them in single setInterval, this is why I am tryng to use cnt(s_, d); if that will work I will write cnt(s_2, d2), cnt(s_3, d3).."

You could just use closures to your advantage here.

```
var rek_inter1 = setInterval(cnt(s_2, d2), 1000),
    rek_inter2 = setInterval(cnt(s_3, d3), 1000);

function cnt(deg, deg2) {
    return function () {
        deg--;
        while (deg < 0) {
            deg = 59;
            deg2--;
        }
        if (deg2 < 0) {
            $('#s_').html("ok");
        } else if (deg2 >= 0) {
            var d_sn = fixd(deg2);
            var s_sn = fixd(deg);
            $('#s_').html(d_sn + ":" + s_sn);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The first attempt is the same as :

```
setInterval ( value, time) ;
```

Here `value = cnt(s_, d)`, the result of the call of the cnt function.
This cannot work, since setInterval expects a function. Too bad it silently fails in javascript.

In the second attempt, the issue is that you modify only function var, so no change can occur : you change deg, deg2, when in fact you would like to change s_ and d.

The third attempt is right, since you both invoke a function and change the globals s_ and d. 
I would rather write it this way :

```
var rek_inter = setInterval( iterate , 1000);

function iterate () {
    s_--;
    while (s_ < 0) {
        s_ = 59;
        d--;
    }
    if (d < 0) {
        $('#s_').html("ok");
    } else if (d >= 0) {
        var d_sn = fixd(d);
        var s_sn = fixd(s_);
        $('#s_').html(d_sn + ":" + s_sn);
    }
}
```

Edit : 
The O.P. mentionned that he wants to handle a set of (s_, d ) parameters.
I suggest you create an array of object which contains such parameters :

```
 var sdParameters = [];
 sdParameters.push( { s : some value , d: some other value} );
 sdParameters.push( { s : some value 2, d: some other value 2 } );
 ... // (or using a for loop to grab the ds and ss if possible)
```

Then after each s/d object is defined by its index, so with :

```
function iterate (ind) {
    var s_ = --sdParameters[ind].s ;       
    while (s_ < 0) {
        s_ = 59;
        sdParameters[ind].d--;
    }
    var d = sdParameters[ind].d;
    if (d < 0) {
        $('#s_').html("ok");
    } else if (d >= 0) {
        var d_sn = fixd(d);
        var s_sn = fixd(s_);
        $('#s_').html(d_sn + ":" + s_sn);
    }
}
```

you can have all your intervals running on one single global array with :

```
     var rek_inter = setInterval( iterate.bind(null,0) , 1000);
     var rek_inter1 = setInterval( iterate.bind(null,1) , 1000);
```

(obviously you can/should store the intervals in an array, you might store them within sdParameters.

One last remark : i couldn't use relevant variable names, since i couldn't guess the use. Using significant names in your code can be of great help when things gets more complex.

Comment: I have lot of s_, s_2, s_3.... and d, d1, d2... values and I want to use them in single setInterval, this is why I am tryng to use cnt(s_, d); if that will work I will write cnt(s_2, d2), cnt(s_3, d3)..